# Is it legal to use force against a person who is illegally trying to disconnect a hospital patient's life support with intent to kill the patient?

Tags: self-defense, any-jurisdiction, defense-of-others

Alice is visiting Bob, who is on life support in a hospital, when Mallory comes into the room and tries to disconnect Bob's life support with intent to kill Bob. Is Alice allowed to use force against Mallory to protect Bob? There is no euthanasia law or other law allowing Mallory to disconnect Bob's life support, and Bob is conscious and actively objects, but is not capable of stopping Mallory on his own.

Comment: Why not?  If use of force to prevent murder is legal then how is your scenario any different?  P.S.  If Bob is on life support it is unlikely he would be conscious and able to consent or not.

Comment: @MichaelHall I wasn't sure if the fact that an external system is what's being directly damaged would make a difference. Maybe I misunderstand the term life support; I thought any external device keeping a person alive was life support. I was quite young at the time, but I believe my grandmother was kept alive by machines for her last few days in the hospital, and she was conscious for part of that time

Comment: In general I think "life support" means a ventilator to keep you breathing artificially, and usually if you can't breath you are in a pretty sever state, but there could be a broader definition.  In any case, if the intent is to cause death it is murder plain and simple.

Comment: Why would you think it isn't legal?

Comment: It looks like a very straight attempt to murder Bob to me. Whether this happens in a hospital by removing life support doesn’t make a difference. Alice can use any proportionate violence to stop Mallory. Killing Mallory and his extended family wouldn’t be proportionate, put anything needed to stop him is.

Comment: @Someone why would you think this was any different from tampering with the brakes of bob’s car?

Comment: probably important: is Mallory some rando, or is he a doctor who the government has charged to kill Bob to save money?

Comment: Planting a bomb, sabotaging someone's car, etc etc all involve the murderer doing something with a device that will cause the victim's death some time later, without the murderer "directly damaging" the victim themselves. Hell, technically that's even true of pointing a gun at someone and pulling the trigger. If messing with life support didn't count as murder, we'd need a **lot** of special case legislation to make sure that all of those other scenarios do.

Comment: It's normal instead for murder laws to be broad enough to cover your scenario already, and instead have special-case legislation is used to cover the situations that **aren't** illegal. (e.g. self-defence, doctors operating in good faith, euthanasia, etc etc etc)

Comment: @Someone: _"I wasn't sure if the fact that an external system is what's being directly damaged would make a difference."_ By that same measure, the weapon you use would be an abstraction - which is clearly not the case. If I shoot someone, it's still murder, even though I only worked a machine (trigger on a gun). Whether I tamper with life support or handle a gun, I'm doing something indirect that ends up causing death. If my intent was to cause death, that's murder.

Comment: Plot twist: According to the doctor's diagnosis, Bob is no longer depending on life support ...

Comment: @gnasher729 In the US, deadly force is generally legal in defense of self or others scenarios if it is the minimum amount of force required to prevent the crime from happening.  In some jurisdictions where it would be only used to prevent proportional crimes, it would still be valid here, since Mallory would commit murder if not stopped by Alice.

Comment: Might you please clarify what you mean by *Bob is conscious and does not consent*? Is *does not consent* the same as **objects**? Is Bob 1) unaware of the attempt to disconnect life support (because e.g. Bob is blind) 2) aware but unable to object (because e.g. Bob cannot speak or move freely, for medical reasons), 3) aware and able to object, but not doing so, or 4) Actively objecting to life support being terminated?

Answer (score 26):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

It depends on Alice's belief about who Mallory is and what Mallory is doing and whether Alice's force was reasonable.

If Alice is aware that Mallory's action is lawful, then Alice cannot use force to protect Bob. Is Mallory a doctor who is lawfully withdrawing treatment? (You say there is "no law allowing Mallory to disconnect Bob's life support" but I'm not aware of a jurisdiction that requires indefinite treatment regardless of the circumstances.)

If Alice honestly believes Mallory is attempting to unlawfully kill Bob, Alice can use force to protect Bob. Is Bob on life support because of Mallory's previous attempt on his life; is Mallory a hitman, a vengeful spouse or some other person with no lawful reason to kill Bob?

[Crown Prosecution Service guidance: Self-Defence and the Prevention of Crime](https://www.cps.gov.uk/legal-guidance/self-defence-and-prevention-crime):

> Self-defence is available as a defence to crimes committed by use of
> force.
>
> The basic principles of self-defence are set out in Palmer v R, [1971]
> AC 814; approved in R v McInnes, 55 Cr App R 551:
>
> "It is both good law and good sense that a man who is attacked may
> defend himself. It is both good law and good sense that he may do, but
> only do, what is reasonably necessary."
>
> The common law approach as expressed in Palmer v R is also relevant to
> the application of section 3 Criminal Law Act 1967:
>
> "A person may use such force as is reasonable in the circumstances in
> the prevention of crime, or in effecting or assisting in the lawful
> arrest of offenders or suspected offenders or of persons unlawfully at
> large." ...

> In assessing the reasonableness of the force used, prosecutors should ask two questions:
>
> - was the use of force necessary in the circumstances, i.e. Was there a need for any force at all?; and
> - was the force used reasonable in the circumstances?
>
> The courts have indicated that both questions are to be answered on the basis of the facts as the accused honestly believed them to be (R v Williams (G) 78 Cr App R 276), (R. v Oatbridge, 94 Cr App R 367).
>
> To that extent it is a subjective test. There is, however, an objective element to the test. The jury must then go on to ask themselves whether, on the basis of the facts as the accused believed them to be, a reasonable person would regard the force used as reasonable or excessive.

Comment: Indefinite treatment isn't required even for conscious patients who want to continue treatment?

Comment: @Someone I should add something like, "indefinite treatment regardless of the circumstances" because there are circumstances when it is lawful to withdraw treatment.

Comment: @Lag The OP's questions was: "Is it legal to use force against a person who is illegally trying to disconnect a hospital patient's life support with intent to kill the patient?" How can Mallory's action be lawful if he is _illegally_ trying to disconnect the equipment?

Comment: The question reads to me as excluding the first possibility, that Mallory's actions could be construed as lawful.  This is emphaised by the sentence you quoted.

Comment: The fact that Mallory's actions were illegal doesn't mean that Alice *knows* this. Her use of force could still be unreasonable depending on the facts she had in her possession at the time.

Comment: @Cadence Per the question, Bob is conscious and does not consent to Mallory's action, which means that Alice would know that Mallory's actions are illegal (how one can be conscious and on life support is beyond me, but if Bob had a will that did not include a DNR statement that Alice is aware of then, that is as good as having a no consent from Bob.

Comment: @hszmv Conscious and being on life-support is nothing weird. E.g. After heart-surgery or lung-surgery it is perfectly normal for a patient to remain on life-support for several days even though he/she is out of anesthesia, because to body isn't quite ready to do it on its own yet.

Comment: @Tonny  Thanks.  I'm not good with medical stuff, so wouldn't know.

Comment: @hszmv :-) Count yourself lucky. I've seen more hospitals on the inside (either for myself or for family members) than I can keep track off. In fact.. As it happens I'm writing this in hospital on my cell-phone while waiting for my wife. She managed to break her wrist a few weeks ago and she is now getting the cast removed.

Comment: @Tonny, Yeah... My medical experience is CPR training when I worked as a lifeguard... which, if you're at the point where you are giving CPR, the vic is unconscious and you're really acting as life support until EMS can arrive with the machines to do the same thing.   Mercifully, I never had anything go that far.

Comment: @hszmv Have CPR training myself too. Never had to use it for real (and I hope I never will) although I have been on standby when a colleague had already started CPR before I reached the scene. (Fellow employee had heart-attack at work.) EMS got there very quick so I didn't need to step in to relieve him. Standard practice here is to switch every 10 minutes (if another trained person is available obviously), since EMS can take up to 30 minutes to arrive in some cases.

Answer (score 15):

### It depends a tad in [germany](/questions/tagged/germany)...

#### Mallory is staff ordered to shut off Life Support

There are cases where life support can be turned off. The two most relevant cases are:

- the conscious patient telling the doctor,
- or the unconscious patient having a *Patientenverfügung*, that demands no life support is performed.

The moment the patient says so or the properly documented paper is in the hands of the doctors for an unconscious patient, they have to end all life-prolonging measures, and shut off life support - in fact, they are not even allowed to start such measures once they are informed of the wish for it.

In a similar fashion, in the absence of such a document and with an unconscious patient, the next of kin might have the life support shut off at some point if they can make it clear that such treatment is against the patient's wishes.

[In Germany, turning off the Life support is **not** (active) euthanasia (which is illegal) but *Behandlungsabbruch* (*end of a medical procedure*), which is defined as the not providing or ending of procedures that could prolong life](https://www.doctors.today/home/a/beatmungsgeraet-abschalten-eine-straftat-1646474). *Behandlungsabbruch* is not a crime, if demanded by the patient or the next of kin can make it clear that it would have been the wish of the patient. In fact, it becomes a crime to **not** turn off the machines the moment that the wish of the patient not to be kept alive is made clear, either by the patient, his *Patientenverfügung*, or verified by the next of kin.

Because Mallory is **not** committing any crime in case he is acting on the Patient's wish (expressed by the conscious patient, unconscious patient's *Patientenverfügung* or unconscious patient's next of kin in absence of a *Patientenverfügung*), Alice can't legally use **any** force against Mallory.

#### Mallory is just out there to murder

Simple case: yes, she may use a reasonable amount of force to stop Mallory. [In fact, she is **obligated** to assist, as long as she is not in danger from that.](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/92391/10334)

Comment: Can *Patientenverfügung* be retracted if, as stated in the question, the patient is "conscious and does not consent"?

Comment: @ToivoSäwén the patient can rescind it, yes

Comment: @ToivoSäwén Not only can the patient retract the Patientenverfuegung, it does not even come into effect as long as the patient is able to express his or her wishes.

Comment: @arne *also* next of kin **can't** override an existing *Patientenverfügung*, only express the patient's possible wishes in case of lack of one.

Comment: Now there’s the question whether Alice knows which category this is. If she doesn’t know and draws a knife to stop Mallory, that will either prevent a murder or slightly delay a legal action. Since a murderer would obviously claim he is acting legally, such a statement cannot be trusted.

Comment: @gnasher729 drawing a knife as the first step oversteps the **necessary** force of the defense of others.

Comment: @Trish: Drawing a knife, not using it. With the threat that a quick action by Mallory could kill Bob. I wouldn’t know how to keep Bob alive if Mallory pulls out random cables.

Comment: @gnasher729 drawing a knife is a lethal threat, which would allow Mallory to actually shoot Alice.

Comment: Not like in the described situation, but a similar incident actually took place. An elderly lady unplugged her roomates life support twice because she was uncomfortable sleeping with the noise. https://www.spiegel.de/panorama/justiz/mannheim-72-jaehrige-frau-schaltet-sauerstoffgeraet-von-bettnachbarin-im-krankenhaus-aus-a-68e76908-d024-4068-a175-733dc0a02cd8

Comment: OP clearly mentions the patient is "conscious" and clearly "does not consent". I doubt any kind of Patientenverfügung could override this.

Comment: The question has been edited to clarify that *Bob is conscious and does not consent* meant *Bob is conscious and actively objects*.  With that clarification, is there any situation where Mallory might be "acting on the Patient's wish" such as previously written wishes taking precedence over current spoken objections?

Comment: @dbc as I had already written, a Patientenverfügung requires an **unconscious** patient. Not sleeping, but really KO. Clarified.

Comment: Trish, assuming Germany where you come from, shooting Alice would not be allowed even for a police officer for a mere threat, but only if they are sure Mallory will die otherwise. Mallory can walk away.

Answer (score 8):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

Alice found Mallory commiting an indictable offence, so Alice can arrest Mallory, using reasonable force. See *Criminal Code*, [s. 494](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-46/section-494.html).

Comment: Most U.S. jurisdictions would be similar.

Answer (score 4):

[germany](/questions/tagged/germany)
Not only is it legal: In Germany, Alice is actually **legally obliged** to do anything that can be reasonably expected from her in order to stop Mallory. [§ 323c StGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stgb/__323c.html) states:

> (1) Wer bei Unglücksfällen oder gemeiner Gefahr oder Not nicht Hilfe leistet, obwohl dies erforderlich und ihm den Umständen nach zuzumuten, insbesondere ohne erhebliche eigene Gefahr und ohne Verletzung anderer wichtiger Pflichten möglich ist, wird mit Freiheitsstrafe bis zu einem Jahr oder mit Geldstrafe bestraft.

*(Anybody who does not render assistance in cases of grave danger or an emergency, even though it is necessary and  within reason, will be put in prison for up to one year or will be fined.)*

In particular, nobody needs to put themselves in serious danger in order to help. Therefore, if Mallory is armed or is raving mad and smashing things left and right you don't have to put yourself in harm's way (but you should still seek help and alert the
authorities).

This legal obligation to render assistance is peculiar to the law systems in the French civil law tradition. By contrast, in jurisdictions in the British common law tradition such an obligation usually does not exist for third parties unrelated to the incident; it only exists for individuals connected to one of the parties or bearing responsibility for the incident.

Answer (score 4):

U.S.:

The United States has some very robust self-defense laws, which would make Alice's actions perfectly legal.   Typically, U.S. self-defense/defense of other laws will cover the minimum amount of force required to prevent a crime from occurring, up to and including lethal force, though because of the U.S. federal nature different states have different laws. New York, for example, requires that the level of force used be proportional to the criminal threat, however, considering the crime is 1st degree murder, lethal force can be used to prevent this type of crime.

In the U.S., it's not uncommon for armed police to remain at hospitals, even outside the door of the patient, especially if they are to be taken into custody (either as an arrest or protective custody... Bob could be a criminal or a witness who a criminal would want to end, as Bob could provide evidence against the criminal targeting him.).

Globally, some of the deadliest serial killers are called "Angels of Mercy" (or "Angels of Death"), who are employees in medical professions or hospitals (doctor, nurses, MediTech's, etc.) who kill patients to end their suffering.  For example, Charlse Cullen, a nurse in New Jersey and PA area hospitals, was arrested in 2003 and convicted of the murder of 29 individuals, the earliest proven one occurring in 1988.   It suspected that he could be responsible for over 400 additional deaths in his 15 year span, but records are not available to prove conclusively.  Compared to non-medical serial killers, Sam Little, who was arrested 2 years later and was active for 20 years longer, was convicted of killing 61 people and is suspected of killing 93.   Ted Bundy was convicted on 20 counts of murder and may have killed more than 100 people.   The most profolific non-medical serial killer in the world, Colombian Luis Garavito is suspected of killing over 300 people, and was convicted of 193.  Angel of Mercy killers, on an average, have a higher suspected victim numbers than non-medical serial killers, as they tend to be active in hospitals and target victims they believe are in pain, seeing as putting them out of their misery (hence the name "Angel of Mercy").  Since their victims are often in serious danger, it's not immediately suspect that they take a sudden turn for the worse.  Cullen the investigation that lead to Cullen's arrest was actually detected by a poison control worker that the hospital called, who noticed that chemicals turning up in patients who died in nurses had no business being in those patients based on the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

In the Netherlands you are always allowed to restrain someone and call for the police or authorities... and when is restraining someone violence? Bit of a grey area I think, a lot of ways to interpret it if it comes to a trial...

If it was one of my loved ones that was being unplugged, I would stop that person no matter what punishment followed - deal with that later .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).